# How do you migrate ExpectedException's syntax from NUnit 2.2.9 to 2.6.3

Tags: vb.net, nunit

In the legacy code using NUnit 2.2.9, the ExpectedException looks like this:

```
<Test(), ExpectedException(GetType(System.Exception), "ExpectedErrorMessage")> Public Sub TestCase
    ' Some test case
End Sub
```

Based on some research that ultimately provided this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/268313/456645, I have this:

```
<Test(), ExpectedException(GetType(System.Exception), ExpectedMessage = "ExpectedErrorMessage")>
```

This produces an error: 'ExpectedMessage' is not declared.  It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I'm using NUnit 2.6.3.13283 and am importing it like this: `Imports NUnit.Framework`.

Comment: According to this, http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exception&r=2.6, this named parameter (ExpectedMessage) should be available.  Perhaps I'm missing something in the translation to vb.net...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for accessing a named parameter is wrong.  It should look like this in VB.Net:

```
<Test(), ExpectedException(GetType(System.Exception), ExpectedMessage:="asdf")>
```

[Passing Arguments by Position and by Name (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51wfzyw0.aspx)